# montage command of ImageMagick does not read from file

Tags: image, terminal, imagemagick, ubuntu-14.04

I use `Ubuntu 14.0.4`. We can use this command to label each image by it's name:

```
montage -label '%t' -size 512x512 "./img/*.*[120x90]" -geometry +5+5 photo.png
```

I want to label images by list of strings, which is written in a text file. [Docs say](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#label):

> -label name
>
> Use this option to assign a specific label to the image ... 
>   If the first character of string is @, the image label is read from a
>   file titled by the remaining characters in the string. Labels in a
>   file are literal, no embedded formatting characters are recognized.

But I could not use a file to provide label. I use a command like this:

```
montage -label @un.txt -size 512x512 "./img/*.*[120x90]" -geometry +5+5 photo.png
```

Above, `un.txt` is the name of text file in `./img/` path. This is a sample result:

[image]

In result, all images labeled by string `@un.txt` instead of content of `un.txt`. Also I get this error in `terminal`:

> montage.im6: improper image header `./img/un.txt' @
>   error/txt.c/ReadTXTImage/429

If I **move** `un.txt` to the current (`.`) directory and run above command again, I will get this image (there is no label) and below error:

[image]

> montage.im6: not authorized `@un.txt' @
>   error/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/2959.

Note:

1. All images are `jpg`
2. The version of ImageMagick is `ImageMagick 6.7.7-10`

Comment: What is the content of `un.txt`?  Also, you are aware that each image will have the same label using that method, right?

Comment: @grochmal The content is a simple string: `test`.

Comment: Could you give your version if imagemagic (e.g `convert -version`)?  (there is a fair chance that Mark's answer below is relevant).  Also, do you intend to have distinct labels for the four images?  (I see a problem with using @labelfile for that.)

Comment: Also, your images are JPEGs right?  (guessing from the examples).  If you have SVG, MSV, MSG images then Mark's answer is very relevant.

Comment: @grochmal I add 2 notes to question, please see them.

Comment: I still find the part *I want to label images by list of strings* a bit confusing.  i.e. I am not sure if we are tackling the right problem.  Even if the command worked, and `un.txt` contained 4 lines of text, then every image will be labeled with these four lines of text.  In other words it will **not** be that every line in `un.txt` will be assigned to one image (that's not how IM works).

Comment: @grochmal Yes! You are OK! I asked this as a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/39378947/1043882). Please see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Maybe you have the wrong syntax for `label`:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:red label:@label.txt -append result.png
```

[image]

where `label.txt` contains `fred`.

**Original Answer**

It is probably related to the vulnerability discovered in ImageMagick, see [here](https://imagetragick.com).

You will need to update your site policy file. You can discover the location by running this:

```
convert -debug configure logo: null: 2>&1 | grep -Ei "Searching|Loading"
```

and it will be in the same directory/folder as the other XML config files.

Comment: That vulnerability is for the XML based images (SVG) and URL loading.  I can read an @labelfile on my IM 6.9.5-8 (which is after the fix), even if I delete my policy.xml and add a URL into the label.  (I may be doing something wrong though, so take it with a grain of salt)

Comment: I remove `<policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*" />` line from `/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml`. Now  montage reads from file, but it does not label  each image by a line of text file. It labels all images by all content of text file. I asked this problem as a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/39378947/1043882), please see it.