# montage does not label images with list of strings represented in text file

Tags: image, terminal, imagemagick

I have a directory (`./img/`) with a large number of images in it. I want to montage them with specific label for each file. I have a text file (`label.txt`) which has list of labels:

> label1
>   label2
>   label3
>   label4
>   ...

I use this command:

```
montage -label @label.txt -size 512x512 "./img/*.*[120x90]" -geometry +5+5 photo.png
```

But in result, all images are labeled by all lines of `label.txt`! How I can separate them, so each image will be labeled by relevant line of `label.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39379677/1043882) represented by [@grochmal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6327365/grochmal) and it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

LABELS=${1:-./labels.txt}
IMAGES=""

readarray labels < "$LABELS"

i=0
echo @ is $@

#copy input argument array in InArg array:
for img in "$@"; do
InArg[$i]=$img
    ((i++))
done

#get dimensions of InArg array:
arraylength=${#InArg[@]}

#extract Input Image array from InArg array:
for (( i=1; i<${arraylength}; i++ ));
do
ImageArray[$i]=${InArg[$i]}
done

#create IMAGES from some elements of InArg array:
for (( i=1; i<${arraylength}; i++ ));
do
IMAGES+=" -label ${labels[i-1]} ${ImageArray[$i]}"
done
echo  "IMAGES is $IMAGES"

echo montage -size 512x512 $IMAGES -font FreeMono-Bold-Oblique -pointsize 30 -geometry '120x90+5+5>' -tile 5x  -frame 5  -shadow out.html
montage -size 512x512 $IMAGES -font FreeMono-Bold-Oblique -pointsize 30 -geometry '120x90+5+5>' -tile 5x  -frame 5  -shadow out.html
```

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick works by parsing the command line and executing the parameters left to right.

Let's say that I have the following images:

```
eh-banner-201606.png
eh-banner-201607.png
eh-banner-201608.png
eh-banner-201609.png
```

(these are some banners for a webstie, the quickest images I have at hand)

Now, if I want to construct a montage with distinct label I must do:

```
montage -font /usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSerif.ttf -size 512x512 \
        -label 'first image' eh-banner-201606.png \
        -label 'second image' eh-banner-201607.png \
        -label 'third image' eh-banner-201608.png \
        -label 'fourth image' eh-banner-201609.png \
        -geometry +5+5 out.png
```

(the `-font` parameter is not strictly needed but I included it for pedantry)

This works as well with `@labelfile`:

```
montage -font /usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSerif.ttf -size 512x512 \
        -label '@first.txt' eh-banner-201606.png \
        -label '@second.txt' eh-banner-201607.png \
        -label '@third.txt' eh-banner-201608.png \
        -label '@fourth.txt' eh-banner-201609.png \
        -geometry +5+5 out.png
```

Where each file will contain a single line (or several lines) that will be the caption for the next image on the command line.

Therefore you need a script to perform what you are after, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

LABELS=${1:-./labels.txt}
IMAGES=""

readarray labels < "$LABELS"
i=0
for img in "$@"; do
    IMAGES+=" -label '${labels[i]}' $img"
    ((i++))
done

echo montage -size 512x512 $IMAGES -geometry +5+5 out.png
montage -size 512x512 $IMAGES -geometry +5+5 out.png
```

You the can do (assuming the script name to be `script.sh`):

```
./script.sh label.txt ./img/*.*120x90
```

**Caveat**: The image files cannot have spaces or special shell characters (that would require a third level of quoting, which is incredibly error prone).  Note that `[` and `]` are special shell characters depending on the context.  If you need more complex handling it may be wiser to use Perl or Python.

Comment: I think you must remove `''` characters around `'${labels[i]}'` in `for` loop and also place a space character between `./img/*.*` and `120*90` in calling `script.sh`. But I get errors again.

Comment: @hasanghaforian - I cannot try to deal with your paths in the script because I do not know it (or in any script, there are just too many path possibilities for scripts to deal with, scripts requiring certain paths are bad practice).  `./script.sh ./l.txt ./1.jpg /path/to/2.jpg ../../3.jpg ../4.jpg` works, even `./script.sh <(cat ./l.txt) ../$(basename $(pwd))/*.jpg`.  In other words you need to provide all paths on the call, globbing happens before a call therefore using `*` is fine, but remember the caveat about special chars in filenames.

Comment: @hasanghaforian - Ah Yeah, the `echo` in there is for debugging purposes.  So you can see how the script interpreted the command line.  i.e. see if the image names are displayed as they should (and if there are any extraneous spaces, a common issue with several levels of quoting + globbing)

Comment: 1upvote for your reply! I changed proposed code and added it as answer.